# DateAdd to a cell when I click the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of dates.  I wan to to write code that adds 7 days to the date in a cell when you click on the cell.  I have tried the following but get 
Option Explicit.  I right clicked the worksheet tab and clicked show code, then entered the code there.  Thanks for any help you can.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J4")) Is Nothing Then
            Cells.Value(Range("J4")) = DateAdd("D", 7, Range("J4"))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want this to happen for any cell, or just for J4?

Comment: every cell in the column, it's only 10 rows so I was going to duplicate the code for each cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you want this to happen for any cell, or just for J4?
>
> every cell in the column, it's only 10 rows so I was going to duplicate the code for each cell.

Then perhaps the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J:J")) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Value = DateAdd("D", 7, Target.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```